# How to optimize createjs web game?

Tags: html, easeljs, createjs

I created a web game with `EaselJS`, which have a few (2-6) Sprites that are moving on the canvas. Also they may scale up and down according to mouse events.

Here is how I move these Sprites:

```
container.enemies.forEach(function(drop) {
    drop.x += drop.vx;
    drop.y += drop.vy;
    checkHitWall(drop);

    var collided = drop.checkCollision(container.enemies);
    if (collided) {
        distributeVelocity(drop, collided);
    }
});
```

Here is how I change their size:

```
growingObject = function(obj) {
  if (obj.radius > canvasWidth / 4) {
    return;
  }
  var rate = 1.01;
  obj.gotoAndStop("growing");

  obj.radius *= rate;
  obj.scaleX = obj.scaleY = obj.scale * rate;
  obj.scale = obj.scaleX;
}
```

and this function is called every tick when mouse is down.

The background is cached when it is created.

I don't know if there's best practice for moving/growing sprites with `EaselJS`.

The game runs find on a desktop browser, but is very laggy on a android phone.

I think these Sprites are not a heavy load for a phone. The profiling result shows `draw` method consumes most CPU time. How could I optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

One idea: You can try reducing your framerate to reach a balance between smooth animation and acceptable speed.  In my experience you can go to surprisingly low framerates on mobile before the game starts looking unacceptable.  Try something like this, and adjust your velocity to simulate the same kind of speed you had at your previous fps.  Obviously the exact tweaking is up to you.

createjs.Ticker.setFPS(12);

Comment: Thank you, that's what I am doing now. I changed the FPS to 30, and it looks much better. I just thought a cell phone could handle more than this with `createJS`.

Comment: I hear you.  I had the same frustration.  Pixi appears to handle multiple animations way better... but I can't really recommend it cause I haven't worked with Pixi yet.